# Machine Learning Sentiment Analysis

Tags: machine-learning, sentiment-analysis

I have chosen another project for my Machine Learning course but it seems it was not fiting the Professor's idea of "project". So I'm trying to find another one.
FRom the 2 months of the course I just know few basics stuff about ML.
I was thinking about doing a Sentiment analysis but I don't know so much about it. Thus, I have to write it in Python and neither I don't know what kind of tools it is better to use nor which kinda dataset I need.I'd like someone to help me in defining how the work should be done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please note that Sentiment Analysis is a broad area, and so you can consider one aspect of it for your project. You can read this paper - [1](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&sqi=2&ved=0CCMQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.uic.edu%2F~liub%2FFBS%2FNLP-handbook-sentiment-analysis.pdf&ei=DJGIVNqGKMipyATNkYCQBQ&usg=AFQjCNGQAPKgEzYY6A1SOph26PrkCqYcaQ&sig2=0YSs11QaDUzIh-TzsHRQ6g&bvm=bv.81456516,d.aWw), which gives you an overall idea of what sentiment analysis is, and what work has been done till date on various aspects of it. Also, this paper -[2](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCUQFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.cs.cornell.edu%2Fhome%2Fllee%2Fpapers%2Fsentiment.pdf&ei=lZGIVMnXPISuyASgpIHgAQ&usg=AFQjCNFpt7e6_MCHDQx5SvaMO005pU3bWA&sig2=A7WabXTU7b9vhk_wHY0kMg&bvm=bv.81456516,d.aWw) will give a brief idea on how machine learning can be used for sentiment classification on movie review datasets.